# Stripping HTML Down To Allowed Tags

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'd like to strip all HTML tags (but not the content), apart from ones given in a list.

I'd like to do this using Node.

The following regex can match tags `<[a|br].+?>|<\/[a]>` but how can I then proceed to remove all tags except the ones matched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To replace only `a` and `br`:**

1. There is no `|` in sets `[]`. The set `[a|br]` is: `a`, `|`, `b` or `r`. Use a non-capturing group instead.
2. `.+?` should be `.*?` to replace `<a>` and `<br>`.
3. The set `[a]` could be just `a`.

Try this:

```
/<(?:a|br).*?>|<\/a>/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/KWJi01/2

**To replace every tag except `a` and `br`:**

Use this regexp:

```
/<(?:(?!\/?a|br).*?)>/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/KWJi01/3

Comment: Ah. This currently matches all of the listed tags- is it possible to make it match all tags _except_ the ones listed (so that I can remove them)?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative solution to the problem, without using regular expressions, is the following approach:

```
// creating a function which takes two arguments:
// htmlString: String, a string of HTML to process,
// permitted:  Array, an array of HTML element tag-names.
function filterHTML(htmlString, permitted) {

  // here we iterate over the Array of permitted elements,
  // and convert any uppercase tag-names to lowercase:
  permitted = permitted.map(
    el => el.toLowerCase()
  );

  // creating a new element in which to hold the passed-in
  // string of HTML when parsed into HTML:
  let temp = document.createElement('div');

  // assigning the passed-in string of HTML as the
  // innerHTML of the temp element:
  temp.innerHTML = htmlString;

  // finding all elements held within the temp element,
  // and passing the NodeList to Array.from() in order
  // to convert the Array-like NodeList into an Array:
  let allElements = Array.from(temp.querySelectorAll('*'));

  // iterating over the array of found elements, using
  // Array.prototype.forEach():
  allElements.forEach(

    // using an Arrow function, 'element' is the current
    // element of the Array of elements over which we're
    // iterating:
    element => {

      // if the current element's tagName - converted to
      // lowercase - is not found within the Array of
      // permitted tags:
      if (permitted.indexOf(element.tagName.toLowerCase()) === -1) {

        // while the current (unpermitted) element has
        // a first-child:
        while (element.firstChild) {

          // we access the element's parent node, and
          // call node.insertBefore() to place the
          // first-child of the element before the
          // element (removing it from the element
          // which is unpermitted and placing it as
          // a previous-sibling):
          element.parentNode.insertBefore(element.firstChild, element);
        }

        // finding the element's parent node, and calling
        // node.removeChild() in order to remove the current
        // element from its parent node (and therefore from
        // the temp element):
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
      }
    });

  // here we return the innerHTML of the temp element, after
  // all unpermitted elements have been removed:
  return temp.innerHTML;
}

// the allowed tags, to be used in the above function,
// note that the tags do not have the '<', '>' or any
// attributes:
let allowedTags = ['br', 'div'];

// the following is just to visually display on the page
// the unprocessed and processed innerHTML, and also the
// rendered HTML following the processing:
document.querySelector('#input').textContent = document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML;

document.querySelector('#output').textContent = filterHTML(document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML, allowedTags).trim();

document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = document.querySelector('#output').textContent;
```

```js
function filterHTML(htmlString, permitted) {
  let temp = document.createElement('div');

  temp.innerHTML = htmlString;

  let allElements = Array.from(temp.querySelectorAll('*'));

  allElements.forEach(
    element => {
      if (permitted.indexOf(element.tagName.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
        while (element.firstChild) {
          element.parentNode.insertBefore(element.firstChild, element);
        }
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
      }
    });
  return temp.innerHTML;
}

let allowedTags = ['br', 'div'];

document.querySelector('#input').textContent = document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML;

document.querySelector('#output').textContent = filterHTML(document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML, allowedTags).trim();

document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = document.querySelector('#output').textContent;
```

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

div[id$=put] {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

#input {
  border-color: #f00;
}

#output {
  border-color: limegreen;
}

::before {
  color: #666;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

#input::before {
  content: 'The original innerHTML of the "#test" element:';
}

#output::before {
  content: 'The filtered innerHTML, with only permitted elements remaining:'
}

#result::before {
  content: 'This element shows the filtered HTML of the "test" element:'
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div><span>
      <a href="#">link text!</a>
      <br />
      <hr />
      <div>div text!</div>
    </span></div>
</div>

<div id="input"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/u1q0gpt3/).

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`let` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).
- [`Node.firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild).
- [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).
- [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).
- [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild).
- [`String.prototype.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
- [`while () {...}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while).